# Array diff only working with first word in array

Tags: php, arrays, echo, explode, implode

using array_diff to filter my array and make sure that if the word is in the filter, it will not be included in the echo. Right now if I replace array2 with "test1, test4" the output will be "test2, test3" which is correct, but instead if I replace array2 with "test2, test4" which should output "test1, test3" I am instead getting an output of "test1, test2, test3" so it is not filtering it out. I know this is probably a very simple fix I am just overlooking it. I will post the code below.

```
<?php
$array1 = "test1, test2, test3";
$array2 = "test2, test4";

$myArray = explode(',', $array1);
$myArray2 = explode(',', $array2);
$unique=array_diff($myArray, $myArray2);
echo implode(',', $unique); 
?>
```

Comment: You need to explode() on comma space, so `', '` or else all but the first have a space as the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `trim` with `array_map`, like below code.

```
$array1 = "test1, test2, test3";
$array2 = "test2, test4";

$myArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $array1));
$myArray2 = array_map('trim', explode(',', $array2));

$unique=array_diff($myArray, $myArray2);
echo implode(',', $unique);
```

Comment: Why not just use the space in the explode()?

Comment: Yes, you are right Mr. @AbraCadaver that can also be used but it may possible that space can be before and/or after the value as well

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` with `,SPACE`

```
$myArray = explode(', ', $array1);
$myArray2 = explode(', ', $array2);
```